# How to use matched location as a variable in Nginx server block?

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I have a nginx server configuration like this:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  root /var/www/html;
  index index.php index.html index.htm;
  server_name example.com www.example.com;

  location /project1/public {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /project1/public/index.php?$query_string;
  }

  location /project2/public {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /project2/public/index.php?$query_string;
  }

  location /project3/public {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /project3/public/index.php?$query_string;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
  }
}
```

and it works. But when I try to use regex (following code) to do this dynamically, it downloads the URL instead of showing it in the browser.

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  root /var/www/html;
  index index.php index.html index.htm;
  server_name example.com www.example.com;

  location ~ ^/([^/]+)/public {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /$1/public/index.php?$query_string;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
  }
}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the order of your location blocks.

If you check the order/priority of the location blocks in [Nginx Docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) there are two rules which are important for your config:

1. If Nginx finds a conventional location block (like `/project1/public`), it does not stop searching and any regular expressions and any longer conventional blocks will be matched first

   --> So in your first config, Nginx first fires your `php-regex` location and then it executes the `try_files`
2. Regular expressions are checked in the order of their appearance in the configuration file. The search of regular expressions terminates on the first match, and the corresponding configuration is used.

   --> In your second config, your `php-regex` is never used since the `try_files` is found first